# Calculating difference in dates in hrs

Tags: javascript

I am working on angular. I have a method which recieves two dates as arguments as follows

```
myMethod(date1, date2) {}
```

Format of both dates is as follows -  "2023-03-27T00:00:00.00Z"

I want to subtract date2 from date1 and want to get result in hrs. How can I do that?

Comment: you can use moment.js for it if you are okay with third party plugin.